# DNN 9.1 custom registration/authentication module

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I want to create a custom registration/authentication module for DNN site. In the past I made a web application with a registration form, but then I used Entity Framework and IdentityUser class, I need to use DAL2 now. Is there a similar way to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For this you will want to create an AuthenticationProvider. It is a special project type and will use the DNN API for any data elements.

The documentation on this model is quite light, but you could review the core authentication provider. There are also third party ones available with source that could be used for education.

This article is old, but looks to still be correct. https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134678/dotnetnuke-tips-and-tricks-12-creating-your-own-authentication-provider